# Removing javascript from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to unload a specific script(example.js) on my html page dynamically, which I can do by

```
var elem = document.getElementById("scid");

elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
```

where **scid** is the script id

but stll the elements of the script remain , as the script once executed leaves its attributes even after removing the  tag.

Is there any way to completely remove the javascript with all its elements and attributes?

Comment: yes. go to the page and edit it.

Comment: What's the end goal you want to achieve by removing the script tag?

Comment: What 'elements and attributes' do you refer to? Global variables etc? Also, do you control the script you want to unload?

Comment: You are just removing the script tag. Your javascript has already been loaded. That why.

Comment: I need the script to unload only after a certain condition butbefore that condition is met , the script is needed so cannot remove in the page.

Comment: “stll the elements of the script remain , as the script once executed leaves its attributes even after removing the tag” — you need to explain in more detail what you mean by this.

Comment: @Paul.D.White by removing/deleting the script tag the DOM elements created by it still remain in the DOM envoirnment. how to remove them also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, once the script has run, the things it defines are part of the JavaScript environment (and possibly the DOM, if the code creates and adds DOM elements). That code is not connected to the `script` element (which can be removed without affecting it).

There is no simple way. You have to find out what the script does and then undo those things individually. For instance, if the script creates global functions `foo` and `bar`, hooks the `resize` event on `window`, and creates new elements on the page, you have to set `foo` and `bar` to `undefined`, remove the `resize` handler (which may be tricky, if you don't have a reference to the function they used to hook it), and remove the new elements on the page.

Comment: is there no other way to do this, maybe a jquery function as I dont have all the references

Comment: @Dev: jQuery might help with removing listeners (event handlers), **if** the script in question hooked up event handlers through jQuery. If you modify the script to use an event namespace for all of its subscriptions (e.g., `.on("click.namespace", ...`), then you can remove those subscriptions using the namespace. In fact, you can remove all event handlers using that namespace on all elements (and window) like this: `$("*").add(window).off(".namespace");`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying using something like RequiredJs (http://requirejs.org/) - which such library you can dynamically load javascript code, in the form of modules. Since that module is an object, once you don't need it you can dispose of it.

It has more advantages, such as caching, lazy-loading scripts... I suggest to see if it suits you needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a way to ask the javascript code to destruct itself from the javascript and dom env.

A sample could be:

```
<script>
    var sample = {
        destroy:function(){/*no matter what it has to clean*/}
    };

</script>
```

then in another piece of code:

```
sample.destroy();
```

Comment: I am loading the script as var fileref=document.createElement('script');
 fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
 fileref.setAttribute("id","scid"); 
 fileref.setAttribute("src", "../scripts/datepicker.js");

Comment: Can you please ellaborate your answer more so i could try it in my code

Comment: so I understand that you are using 3rd party javascript. Then you loose the control how they manage their javascript lifecycle. My proposal is only working for your own javascript which you can control and can design the lifecycle management by youself.

Answer (score 0):

The examples given still return style and script text NOT just the text of the web page. Try this:

```
function funcTextOnlyFromHTML(thedocument){

  var varArrScripts = thedocument.getElementsByTagName("script");

  for(var i = 0; i < varArrScripts.length; i++){
     varArrScripts[i].innerText = "";
  }

  var varArrStyles = thedocument.getElementsByTagName("style");

  for(var i = 0; i < varArrStyles.length; i++){
     varArrStyles[i].innerText = "";
  }

  return thedocument.body.innerText;
}
```